# What are the differences between msg.sender, tx.origin, and ethereum accounts?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to solve the problem of contract access and I understand from the very informative documentation that owner should be assigned to msg.sender by a constructor when the contract is created. Does that mean the *original account which deployed the contract* is then the owner? How does that relate to tx.origin?

How **secure** of the msg.sender test and can this be extended to for example securing a function for a set of approved accounts also stated when the contract is created in the constructor?

I also saw payable not stated in the following example. Is that because *constructors do not need payable* when updating a state variable?

Code example -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Coin {
// The keyword "public" makes those variables
// readable from outside.
address public minter;
mapping (address => uint) public balances;

// Events allow light clients to react on
// changes efficiently.
event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

// This is the constructor whose code is
// run only when the contract is created.
function Coin() public {
    minter = msg.sender;
}

function mint(address receiver, uint amount) public {
    if (msg.sender != minter) return;
    balances[receiver] += amount;
}

function send(address receiver, uint amount) public {
    if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return;
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balances[receiver] += amount;
    Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
}
}
```

Comment: Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.